# Presta shop adding products with PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I have a question about importing products directly to Prestashop database.

I'm adding the products with sql statment to all the required tables in the database. The products show up in the back-office the only problem that i have is that the products dont show up on the web page.

When i navigate to the product section in the back office the problem seems to be the defualt category and link rewrite. I get an error that the defualt category is not set although every table that containes the id_category_default field is set up the right way.

I could use some help in how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set in ps_product.id_category_default the key of table **ps_category.id_category**

Comment: allready done that. Its really wierd. When i go to the back office and manualy save the product without changing anything, the product is shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your link rewrite ? You'll need to generate this yourself in your import script if you're importing directly into the SQL.

Also make sure you have added the text for each language that you use on the site.